# Get product ids by sku first characters using a shortcode from an URL in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have multiple products, whose sku names are like AL-888, A-2323, AL-etrere. 
I want to find products on basis of this sku name's first two words.

I am creating shortcode for this purpose, but can't able to get it work.

Any help should be appreciated.

Code for this shortcode:

```
 function all_state_list_function(){

   $name = $_GET['sku']; //this give sku value from url like Al:2323

   echo $name;

  $args = array( 
      'post_type'       => 'product', 
      'posts_per_page'  => -1, 
      'orderby'         => 'name',
      'order'           => 'DESC',
      'meta_query' => array(
         'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
            'key'     => 'free_form',
            'value'   => '1',
         ),
         array(
            'key'     => '_sku',
            'value'   => $name.'-%',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
         ),
      ),
   );

   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

      $product_id = get_the_ID(); 
      echo $product_id;

   endwhile;

   wp_reset_query(); 

}
add_shortcode( 'all_state_list_shortcode', 'all_state_list_function' );
```

Comment: can you please first post what you have tried already, or at least how are you displaying the custom array items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your first version code that had an SQL query, here is the correct way to get product IDs from first SKU characters value using GET method from an URL:

```
add_shortcode( 'all_state_list_shortcode', 'all_state_list_function' );
function all_state_list_function(){
    if ( isset($_GET['sku']) && ! empty($_GET['sku']) ) {

        ob_start();

        $sku = esc_attr( $_GET['sku'] ) .'%';

        global $wpdb;
        $results = $wpdb->get_col( "
            SELECT p.ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
            JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
            WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product' AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
            AND meta_key LIKE '_sku' AND meta_value LIKE '$sku'
        " );

        if( count($results) > 0 ) {
            echo implode(',', $results);
        } else {
            echo 'Nothing found';
        }

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.